# Static file not being included in yocto image

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

I'm trying to include a static file in a yocto image. The file does not need anything done to it, just be included. I'm appending core-image-minimal. However, after the image is built, the file is not available.

The file structure is:

```
custom-layer
---recipes-file
------files
---------blink.rbf
------rbftest.bb
```

I changed the layers conf file to be able to find the recipe.

If I do `bitbake rbftest` everything seems to work, no errors and the file is in the tmp work directory.

This is the recipe:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS:prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"
 
SRC_URI += "file://blink.rbf"
 
FILES:${PN} += "${datadir}/blink.rbf"
 
do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${datadir}/
    install -m 755 ${WORKDIR}/blink.rbf ${D}${datadir}
}
```

`rbftest.bb`

relevant line from `conf/local.conf`

`IMAGE_INSTALL:appened = " rbftest"`

When I run `bitbake -e core-image-minimal | grep IMAGE_INSTALL` I get.

```
IMAGE_INSTALL="packagegroup-core-boot "
IMAGE_INSTALL:appened=" rbftest"
```

Comment: Use `FILES_PN`
    FILES_PN += "/usr/share/*"

Comment: @void_brain I changed `FILES:${PN} += "${datadir}/blink.rbf"` to `FILES_PN += "/usr/share/*"`. When I `bitbake rbftest` I get an error `Files/directories were installed but not shipped in any package`. I do not get this error if I run `bitbake core-image-minimal`. I checked the image and the file did not get included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rbftest` is not added to `IMAGE_INSTALL` because you mistyped `append`

```
IMAGE_INSTALL:appened=" rbftest"
               ^
               |
================
```

it should be : `IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " rbftest"`

Make sure to get the final value of `IMAGE_INSTALL`:

```
bitbake -e core-image-minimal | grep ^IMAGE_INSTALL=

or

bitbake-getvar -r core-image-minimal --value IMAGE_INSTALL
```

Note: I don't understand why your recipe file ends with `rbf`.

Comment: Thank you, that was it! The recipe file ending with rbf was a typo in my question, I seem to be prone to them.